# Nested lists in 3 levels with string and booleans

Tags: python, python-3.x

I trying to create a 3 level nested list, from a nested list called lst and a list containing boolean values. But I can't figure out how to construct the new list correct.

Here is my code so far:

```
lst = [["Family=252.007 - SE.540x540"], ["Family=252.001 - SE.540x540"], ["Family=252.025 - SE.540x540"]]

booleanList = [True, True, False]

newList = [list(i) for i in zip(lst, booleanList)]
print(newList)
```

The result I get:

```
newList = [[['Family=252.007 - SE.540x540'], True], [['Family=252.001 - SE.540x540'], True], [['Family=252.025 - SE.540x540'], False]]
```

The list I want to create, should look like this:

```
newList = [[["Family=252.007 - SE.540x540"], [True]],[["Family=252.001 - SE.540x540"],[True]], [["Family=252.025 - SE.540x540"], [False]]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
lst = [["Family=252.007 - SE.540x540"], ["Family=252.001 - SE.540x540"], ["Family=252.025 - SE.540x540"]]
booleanList = [True, True, False]

newList = [[c, [b]] for c, b in zip(lst, booleanList)]

print(newList)

[[['Family=252.007 - SE.540x540'], [True]],
 [['Family=252.001 - SE.540x540'], [True]],
 [['Family=252.025 - SE.540x540'], [False]]]
```

Answer (score 2):

## Option 1:

You can simple change those bool into:
change:

```py
booleanList = [True, True, False]
```

into:

```py
booleanList = [[True], [True], [False]]
```

## Option 2:

If you want to do it danamicly i would change it into:

```py
newList = [[d,[b]] for d,b in zip(lst, booleanList)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want something like that:

```py
newBooleanList = [[j] for j in booleanList]
newList = [list(i) for i in zip(lst, booleanList)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with one var:

```
newList = [[i[0],[i[1]]] for i in zip(lst, booleanList)]
```